# PL/SQl question, oracle 9i

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle9i

We have a scenario here where we need to return the car if the below condition is not true and not return anything (or null)if its true

```
table-> from car_list 
condition where color = red and color_tinge = light and car = ?
```

now there can be multiple values for color = red and color tinge = anything... and we need only the ones which satisfy both cases.
Here is sample data of the table:

```
car   color   color_tinge
a1    red     light
a2    red     dark
a1    green   light
a3    blue    dark
```

the output data should be car# if the condition is not true( we are passing 
the car number to the condition) and null or nothing if the condition is true

any help is appreciated!

Comment: Sorry, your description is very confusing. Can you expand by adding  output data and expected conditions that would pass and fail?

Comment: Please, provide us with more data samples (i.e. desided output) so that we can better understand your needs.

Comment: ok ive updated hte original question, basically what we need as output is the car# if the condition fails (ie both color=red and color tinge=light is not true) or null as output if the condition is true for given car number

Answer (score 2):

select car 
from car_list 
where 
  not (color = 'red' and color_tingle = 'light')
  and car = car_id;

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE
myCar VARCHAR(20);
```

and then...

```
SELECT
   car
FROM
   table
WHERE
   color != 'red' AND tinge != 'light' AND car = myCar
```

Or...

```
SELECT
   DECODE (color, 'red', DECODE (tinge, 'light', 'FAIL', 'PASS'), 'PASS')
FROM
   table
WHERE
   car = myCar
```

Comment: unfortunately this does not consider car id in the query

Comment: it will give you all the car id's for the cars that are not light red.  Isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: i want to pass the car id with it too and then check for the stated condition as mentioned on top

Answer (score 0):

Initialize...

> CREATE TABLE YOURTABLE   (
>       CAR   VARCHAR2(20 BYTE),
>       COLOR VARCHAR2(20 BYTE),
>       TINGE VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)   );    INSERT INTO YOURTABLE VALUES
>   ('a1','red','light');
>
> INSERT INTO YOURTABLE VALUES ('a2','red','dark');
>
> INSERT INTO YOURTABLE VALUES ('a1','green','light');
>
> INSERT INTO YOURTABLE VALUES ('a3','blue','dark');
>
> COMMIT;
>
> SELECT * FROM YOURTABLE;

Then...

```
SET serveroutput ON
DECLARE
  ret VARCHAR2(10);
  CURSOR c_cur (p1 VARCHAR2)
  IS
    SELECT COUNT(1)
    FROM YOURTABLE
    WHERE color = 'red'
    AND tinge   = 'light'
    AND CAR     = p1;
BEGIN
  OPEN c_cur('a2');
  FETCH c_cur INTO ret;
  IF ret = 1 THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('pass');
  ELSE
    dbms_output.put_line('fail');
  END IF;
END;
```

Answer (score -2):

This will return either `car#ID` or `NULL`. Not sure if I understand correctly what you want.

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN EXISTS
        ( SELECT *
          FROM car_list 
          WHERE color = red 
            AND color_tinge = light
            AND car = car#ID
        ) 
      THEN NULL
      ELSE car#ID
    END AS Result
FROM dual
```

---

Would this work?

```
SELECT Result
FROM
  ( SELECT
        CASE WHEN EXISTS
            ( SELECT *
              FROM car_list 
              WHERE color = red 
                AND color_tinge = light
                AND car = car#ID
            ) 
          THEN NULL
          ELSE car#ID
        END AS Result
    FROM dual
  ) tmp
WHERE Result IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: instead of null can we get this to output the normal "no rows selected"?

Comment: Sandy, in your origianl question you specifically ask for the query to return NULL, now you want it to return "no rows selected"?